# How to get the WordPress Username in a contacts or membership export

Tags: wordpress, civimember, export

Is it possible to include the WordPress username in the export of contact & membership details? We would like to include it in a mailmerge for new members who joined by post.

Thanks

Steve

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible with the built-in export, no. Do you have sql access to the CiviCRM database? The connection between CiviCRM and the CMS is stored in the table `civicrm_uf_match`.